# jquery not returning required element using '$(this)'

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

The following $(this) does not seem to be returning $('.element'). Any ideas why?

```
$('.element').popover({
  container: $(this)
})
```

Comment: Because the scoping isn't correct. You're setting an objects properties.

Comment: [Maybe you should check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What's the link to the plugin you're using? I'll look at the documentation and see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by others, the context of this isn't as you perhaps expected. Perhaps try looping over all the elements.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    $(this).popover({
        container: $(this)
    });
});
```

Inside the scope of the each function, $(this) will refer to a specific $('.element') from the list of all the elements with that class.

Answer (score 4):

That's because popover is not an event function, but rather a function that applies some properties to an object.

You can however use **each** to iterate through every element :

```
$('.element').each(function(i, obj) {
   obj.popover({
      container: obj
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular context, `this` will refer to whatever happens to be the outer scope. It could be the `window` object, or some containing function.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var obj = {container: $(this)}; // <-- this is defined in outer scope

$('.element').popover(obj);
```